# Capistrano git:check failed exit status 128

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I got this when I ran `cap production git:check`. (I took out my real ip address and user name)

```
DEBUG [4d1face0] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h foo@114.215.183.110:~/git/deepot.git on 114.***.***.***
DEBUG [4d1face0] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/deepot/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h foo@114.***.***.***:~/git/deepot.git )
DEBUG [4d1face0]        Error reading response length from authentication socket.
DEBUG [4d1face0]        Permission denied (publickey,password).
DEBUG [4d1face0]        fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
DEBUG [4d1face0] Finished in 0.715 seconds with exit status 128 (failed).
```

Below is my deploy file...

```
set :user, 'foo'
set :domain, '114.***.***.***'
set :application, 'deepot'

set :repo_url, 'foo@114.***.***.***:~/git/deepot.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/#{fetch(:user)}/local/#{fetch(:application)}'

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/bmap.yml config/cloudinary.yml config/environments/development.rb config/environments/production.rb}
```

Below is my production.rb...

```
role :app, %w{foo@114.***.***.***}
role :web, %w{foo@114.***.***.***}
role :db,  %w{foo@114.***.***.***}

server '114.***.***.***', user: 'foo', roles: %w{web app}, ssh_options: {keys: %w{/c/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa}, auth_methods: %w(publickey)}
```

I can successfully ssh on to my `foo@114.***.***.***` without entering any password using git bash. (I am windows 7 machine and deployment server is ubuntu 12.04)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try generating a new private/public key par and provide a passphrase for it. If it works, the problem is your current key doesn't use a passphrase.