# How to add ssh key to docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, docker, ssh, capistrano

I have existing Rails application with Capistrano for deployment. Now my team switched this project to Docker. 
When I'm trying

```
docker-compose run web cap production git:check
```

I have git exit status: 128. I know it's a problem with ssh from Docker.

Can I add SSH key into Docker container and run cap production deploy?

Comment: Hello, there is not really much information to go from since you probably created the docker image on your own (your team did). I saw this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712481/capistrano-gitcheck-failed-exit-status-128) already being answered. In general you should try to avoid adding keys to an image but try to use them either during the build of the image or as environmental variable which you could access within your docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use volumes, to mount your ssh key inside container: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

like:

`volumes:
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`